# Drop down Menu in navbar remains on top of all the fixed elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu in a nav-bar. Below it (below the nav-bar) there is a `div` whose position is fixed. When I open the drop down menu it goes behind that `div`. I already tried `z-index` but it's not working. I also made the position of the dropdown menu "fixed" but it did not show any thing.

Below is my code:

```
.dropdownmenu{
  background-color : #333;
  opacity : 0.95;
  z-index : 9999;
}
```

and html code of navbar in which drop down menu is:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop" data-toggle="dropdown"       role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>
            <%= session['user-session']%>
        </strong>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu drop">
    <li><a href="#">My Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Logout","/users/logout"%></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

js code is:

```
$(document).scroll(function () 
    {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var topDist = $("#navbar").position();
        if (scroll > topDist.top) {
            $('.navbar').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","z-index":"1"});

        if($('#search').css("position") == "fixed"){
            $('#search').css({"position":"fixed" , "marginTop":"80px"});}
        }
        else if (scroll == topDist.top) {
            $('.navbar').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","z-index":"1"});

        if($('#search').css("position") == "fixed"){
            $('#search').css({"position":"fixed" , "marginTop":"0px"});
            $('.navbar').css({"position":"static","top":"auto"});}
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar').css({"position":"static","top":"auto"});
        }
    });
```

id #search is the id of below div

here is the code of search div which is fixed. menu hides behind it.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="searchDiv">
            <div class="panel panel-default serachpanel" id="search" style="height:83%;position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll;z-index: -1;">
                <div class="panel-heading">Search Persons</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>To optimize your search rresults,provide picture of </p>
                        <p>person with a clear face to do search by picture.</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <div id="image-holder"></div>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                        <input id="fileUpload" type="file" class="btn-success"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>Enter Date and Time You want to search from:</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            ............
```

Comment: Use some postion, relative or absolute, because this way takes static position, so, it's doesn't work.

Comment: yes i used position. but the div below has a position fixed. thats why dropdown menu hides behind it. i gave dropdown menu fixed position but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Bootstrap Components](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) page to make sure you are using the correct markup. Markup for dropdowns inside of navbars is as follows:

```
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Hopefully this helps.

**EDIT:**

In your JS code, `"z-index":"1"` will set your z-index to 1, change these values and see if that helps.

**EDIT 2:**

Everything contained in  `<div class="panel panel-default serachpanel" id="search" style="height:83%;position: fixed; overflow-y: scroll;z-index: -1;">` should be at `z-index: -1;` this leads me to believe that its likely the `<div class="col-sm-4" id="searchDiv">` div causing this issue. For an easier testing paradigm I would suggest using the Inspect Element editor in Google Chrome, you should test each one of the CSS modifiers for that element (and all the subsequent elements). Let me know if that doesn't work.

*As a side note: `serachpanel` in the above code should be searchpanel, is that intentional or a typo?*

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with your navbar and the offending element? It is likely the fault of the element, Bootstrap usually does a good does a good job of keeping its css in line.

Comment: i just use simple bootstrap. the code is same as you write above.

Comment: Can you post the code for your element. That is the HTML, the CSS, and any JS that affects it?

Comment: One other thing, the dropdownmenu class isn't defined in Bootstrap, have you added that class to your html div? it should read: <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownmenu">

Comment: We also need to see the code for the offending element that's where we are going to see why the element is in front of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual code its really hard to tell what seems to be the problem. From the CSS you posted, I can see you've added `z-index` property to an element which is not positioned, or rather has a static position. `z-index` only works on positioned elements (that is, ones with any position other than static) and their descendants.

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and
>   its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.
>
> For a positioned box (that is, one with any position other than
>   static), the z-index property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> - Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

---

You could try to add position: relative to your selector. It might not work in your case, but as I said, without some actual code, my guess is good as any.

```
.dropdownmenu {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #333;
    opacity: 0.95;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: by giving position relative, when menu open it not appear on above of the div but it drag the div down and makes its position.